# BufferedImage Read from file using ObjectStream is null

Tags: serialization, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

### Description

Im reading Theme Objects from a file, the Theme class has a list of buffered images that is transient, but uses a custom read/write Object method that uses ImageIO's read and write.
The Problem is that the first BufferedImage I read in a Theme is always ok(not null) but the rest is null, I think there might be something wrong with the writeObject method, but what?

The program goes trough folders and creates a Theme containing images that where located in that folder. There is nothing wrong with the Images, I've checked using different images, but the result is the same.

---

### DataSetup

```
public class DataSetup {

    public void write() {

        List<Theme> themes = getThemes(new File("data"));

        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/campaign.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            for(Theme theme : themes) {

                oos.writeObject(theme);
            }

            oos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

### Theme Class

```
package data;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Theme implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private transient List<BufferedImage> bufferedImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage();

    public Theme(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {

        oos.defaultWriteObject();
        oos.writeInt(bufferedImages.size());

        for(BufferedImage bi : bufferedImages) {

                    //Image type is JPG
            ImageIO.write(bi, Data.IMAGE_TYPE, oos);
        }
            oos.close();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ois.defaultReadObject();
        final int COUNT = ois.readInt();

        bufferedImages = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(COUNT);

        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {

            bufferedImages.add(ImageIO.read(ois));
        }

        System.out.println("Checking for Theme " + getName());
        for(BufferedImage bi : bufferedImages) {

            System.out.println("Image is null = " + (bi==null));
        }
            ois.close();
    }

    public void addBufferedImage(BufferedImage bi) {bufferedImages.add(bi);}
    public BufferedImage getBufferedImage(int index) {return bufferedImages.get(index);}

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public int getSize() {return bufferedImages.size();}
}
```

### Output

```
Checking for Theme Animal
Image is null = false
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
Checking for Theme Clown
Image is null = false
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
Checking for Theme Mountain
Image is null = false
Image is null = true
Checking for Theme Space
Image is null = false
Image is null = true
Image is null = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a known issue.

There's no guarantee that the `ImageReader` will read as many bytes as the `ImageWriter` originally wrote. It will read as many bytes as needed to efficiently decode (due to buffering, this might be *more* than the writer wrote, as the stream just continues). This might lead to the stream being "mis-aligned", and the next read(s) will fail.

The workaround is to buffer each write, then write the length (byte count) for each image, before the actual image bytes, or simply write the buffered byte arrays.

When reading back, make sure you have consumed exactly as many bytes as you wrote, by reading or skipping the necessary number of extra bytes.

To write, you can use code similar to:

```
BufferedImage image = null; // your image
ByteArrayOutputStream bufferStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", bufferStream);

byte[] bufferedBytes = bufferStream.toByteArray();

// Write bufferedBytes to ObjectOutputStream as Object, OR write bufferedBytes.length + bufferedBytes as raw bytes
```

To read:

```
byte[] bytes = ...; // from ObjectInputStream
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Comment: I tried this: byte[] bytes = ((DataBufferByte) bi.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData(); and then saving the length and the bytes to the file(size of the file became 85 mb) using the objectstream. I then read it like this: ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)), after reading the values back, but that didnt work. I cant seem to understand how to buffer each write, should I use ByteArrayStreams to write and read? And in my DataSetup should I still use ObjectOutputStream as my Theme class still uses default read/write Object?

Comment: ImageIO doesn't read raw bytes, so if you write the raw bytes of the image, you will have to implement custom reading as well. I don't recommend doing it that way, as it requires a lot of work if you want it to work for arbitrary images. I updated the answer with a code example, for a simple way to do buffered writes.

Comment: Thanks Harald, your method worked, and now it starts to make sense why I had to do it this way. Much appreciated explanation.